# How to update third party props value - Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using `ant calendar` which renders PanelBody(third party) component which has a prop call `rowNum`. Now I want to override this value to my custom value from my component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { getEventInfo, getQuest } from '../../../response/api';
import { EventInfo, Event } from '../../../response/type';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import jaJP from 'antd/lib/locale/ja_JP';


interface State {
  event_infos: EventInfo[];
  events: Event[];
}

interface Props {
}

class EventCalendar extends React.Component<Props, State>  {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      event_infos: [],
      events: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getEventInfo().then((item) => {
      this.setState({event_infos: item});
    });

    getQuest().then((item) => {
      this.setState({events: item});
    });
  }

  getCorrectFormatDate = date => {
    return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }

  getListEventInfoDate = value => {
    let listData = [];
    let listEventInfo = this.state.event_infos;

    listEventInfo.map((item) => {
      const startTime = this.getCorrectFormatDate(item.start_at);
      const calendarTime = this.getCorrectFormatDate(value);

      if (startTime === calendarTime) {
        listData.push(item);
      }
      return listData;
    });

    return listData || [];
  }

  getListEventDate = value => {
    let listData = [];
    let listEvent = this.state.events;

    listEvent.map((item) => {
      const startTime = this.getCorrectFormatDate(item.start_at);
      const calendarTime = this.getCorrectFormatDate(value);

      if (startTime === calendarTime) {
        listData.push(item);
      }
      return listData;
    });

    return listData || [];
  }

  dateCellRender = value =>{
    const listEventInfos = this.getListEventInfoDate(value);
    const listEvents = this.getListEventDate(value)

    return (
      <ul className="events-calendar">
        {listEventInfos.map((item, i) => <img key={i} src={item.image} alt="event_info" />)}
        {listEvents.map((item, i) => <Button key={i} variant="outlined" color="primary" className="button-event">{item.name}</Button>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  render() {
    moment.locale("ja");
    return(
      <ConfigProvider locale={jaJP}>
        <Calendar
          dateCellRender={this.dateCellRender}
          className="hide-header"
          validRange={[moment('2020-12-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), moment('2021-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD')]}
          defaultValue={moment('2020-12-13')}
        />
      </ConfigProvider>
    )
  }
};

export default EventCalendar;
```

This component render `Calendar` which renders `PanelBody`. I tried to create a duplicated component then overrided the prop value, imported it to `EventCalendar`, but it cannot update the props value as expected. Is it my approach wrong? Any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Can you please share the internal code of the `Calendar` component ?

Comment: @usafder `Calendar` component is from antd design.